# PyQt Multithreading example

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt

Chances are I'm way too tired and need to sleep as I have done threading before but all of a sudden I'm coming across a common error which states:

> 'global name 'self' is not defined'.

Here is the code before I input the threading function,

```
import thread
import time
import ystockquote
import Tkinter as tk
from threadexample import *
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *



class Window(QtGui.QDialog):



    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        style = QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks')
        app.setStyle(style)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = Window()
    viewer.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and here it is with the threading function referred to as (`start_stream`),

```
import thread
import time
import ystockquote
import Tkinter as tk
from threadexample import *
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *



class Window(QtGui.QDialog):



    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        style = QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks')
        app.setStyle(style)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.startbutton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.start_stream)

    def start_stream( threadName, delay):
        while True:
            footsie = ystockquote.get_price('^FTSE')
            self.ui.indexlabel.setText(footsie)

    try:
        thread.start_new_thread( start_stream, ("Now Streaming", 5,))
    except:            
        self.ui.indexlabel.setText("Error")

    while True:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = Window()
    viewer.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please edit your question and fix all the indenting in your code examples,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):   
    ...
    def start_stream(threadName, delay):
        ...
```

`start_stream` is missing the `self` parameter, so when you try to access it within the method, `self` will be not defined.

Comment: There's also an undefined `self` reference in the try/except block defined in the `Window` class body. And WTF is that `while True: pass` doing there?!

Comment: I have tried changing it to def start_stream(self, threadName, delay) and get Error: start_stream() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Don't try to start a thread directly within the class body, eithe move it into `__init__` or its own function, the class body is evaluated when the class is defined, there is no instance at that point. And you should use the newer [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module instead of `thread.start_new_thread`.